# What are the possible effects that deleting UAService.exe could have on my computer/OS?

Tags: windows-7, blocking, web-filtering

Thanks to my EXTREMELY annoying school policy, I am unable to run and .bat, .exe, .wav, .mp4, .mp3, etc. files on my computer. I have tracked down the Lightspeed User Service, and am wondering what effect deleting that file will have (Will it unblock files but keep system from booting, or do nothing at all, etc.).

I have verified that UAService.exe is a legitimate file, and not malware. My school uses lightspeed and zenworks (I think a branch of lightspeed) to disallow certain files on my computer, which has become very limiting to me.

Comment: Policies are applied for some reason be it at a school or office & if you are seeking help to break them here, its not the right place.

Comment: I'm not seeking help to break them, im seeking answers to the possible effects breaking them would have on the system. breaking them is easy.

Comment: your sole idea behind knowing that is to enable yourself to run .bat, .exe etc files which are blocked

Comment: It's **not** your computer. It belongs to your school.

Comment: @mrdorkface - Any answers we give you would bypass and more then likely break the policy.  The community decided awhile ago questions like this are outside of the scope here at Superuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not part of Windows so it wouldn't stop your machine booting, it may however break whatever program it's installed for. As to whether it will unblock files there's no way of knowing unless you know which programs use it.

You shouldn't be tampering with school machines and if their security is set up well they will know you did.

So in answer to your question the possible effects of deleting the service are:-

1) you get caught and end up in trouble

2) you don't get caught but you're still blocked

3) you don't get caught and you've managed to break a program in your schools computer

Comment: They reinstall windows on every computer in between school years, and everyone gets the same one every year, so I doubt there will be any permanent damage. Now to create a restore point, delete it, reboot, and see what happens

Comment: you'd need to stop the service and uninstall, not delete it I think

Comment: I believe those would have very similar effects, but thanks anyways.